# Python for loop exclude certain folder names - regex

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a for loop that walks through the root directory I give it and recursively looks through all the folders for certain strings in files. However I want to exclude certain folders from being recursively looked at, and to skip their contained files.

I currently have the below that works with the static values, "values-af", "values-am". However I have 91 of "values-##" and so don't want to list all variations. I attempted a reg ex in the variable 'skip' however cannot get this working correctly.

```
rootpath=outDir
#skip=re.compile('values-([\w])+')
exclude=set(['values-af','values-am'])
for path,name,fname in os.walk(rootpath):
    name[:] = [d for d in name if d not in exclude] 
    [more code]
```

How would I go about implementing a correct regex in the above code to match anything after the word 'values' 
eg. values-gf, values-fgh-rHK, values-h24, values-g4dghd

tl;dr got working code but need to implement a working regex to and exclude everything after "values"

Comment: apologies, I did attempt to search. Looking at other thread now.

Answer (score 0):

One general possibility would be the following:

```
rootpath=outDir
skip = ["str-am", "str-de", "str-es"]
    for path,name,fname in os.walk(rootpath):
        if name in skip: # or path in skip or fname in skip, whatever you want
            continue
        # Stuff
```